# Error reading data from json file in Angular

Tags: angularjs, json

The same piece of code was working on a different machine. How can I solve this issue?

**Code:**

```
mainApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope,$http){
    $http.get('./data.json')
    .success(function(response){
        $scope.record = response.data;
```

**Error:**

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/reddy/Angular/data.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: COORS issue.  When you are on the server `./data.json` request goes to something like `http://<yourDomain>/data.json` which is in the same domain as the page you just loaded into the browser.  `file:///C:/Users.../data.json` is considered a different domain and chrome will complain.

Comment: file:///C:/Users/reddy/Angular/index.html is the url

Comment: It is working in Firefox..

Comment: Firefox is less strict about COORS

Comment: Do you have server that load your application or clean html, js?

Comment: I don't have any server. It's just a html and JS file.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are simply looking to eliminate the problem when working in Chrome you can add a chrome extension like this one:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en